# React Native CallKeep Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to use react native callkeep module (https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) for a audio/video call app and I am having this issue in the part of installation for iOS (https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/blob/master/docs/ios-installation.md#4-updating-appdelegatem) we add a function but its giving this warning

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
 continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
   restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
 {
   return [RNCallKeep application:application
            continueUserActivity:userActivity
              restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
 }
```

can that give a problem for my application I haven't compiled and tried it but seems there is a type conflict or something but I can't understand exactly since I have no experience on Obj-C

Comment: Your `restorationHandler` declaration doesn't constrain the array to `UIUserActivityRestorin`. Easiest thing is to delete the method, start typing it again and let Xcode auto complete the signature.

Comment: thank you typing it again solved the issue

Comment: any updates here?
Have similar problem, but i need to declare another continueUserActivity for LinkingIOS. Does anyone faced this?